# Why does UrlConnection via Proxy server not require authentication, but commons HttpClient does require it?

Tags: java, proxy, connection, urlconnection, apache-commons-httpclient

This is my first post here, but its one I've been struggling with for two days without any result.

I am installing a Java application on a hosted machine that has an internet proxy server.

When I use web browsers on this particular machine, they don't require any authentication - just the proxy host and port details.

When I run the following simple program that uses a UrlConnection, all it requires to get it running correctly are the proxy host and port also.

```
    public class TestProxyConnectionUrlConnection {
```

```
    public void runUrlConnection() {
      try {
        String host = "proxy-local.net";
        String port = "8080";
        System.setProperty( "http.proxyHost", host);
        System.setProperty( "http.proxyPort", port);
        System.setProperty( "http.useProxy", "true");
        URL url = new URL("http://mydomainb.com/myservice");
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        yc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        yc.setDoOutput(true);
        yc.setDoInput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(yc.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><xmlcontent>content</xmlcontent>");
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( yc.getInputStream()));
        try {
          String inputLine;
          String response = "";
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              response = inputLine;
          }
        }
        finally {
          in.close();
        }
        System.out.println(response);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

However, when I run code that uses Apache Commons HttpClient to talk to the server, as per the next bit of code, the proxy server is responding with a 407 error, and requesting NTLM or Kerberos authentication.

* Note we are stuck in using HttpCommons v3.1 for the time being due to a web-service product that uses it also.

```
public class TestProxyConnectionHttpCommons {

    public void runHttpClient() throws Exception {
      HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
      try {
        String host = "proxy-local.net";
        String port = "8080";
        ProxyHost pxy = new ProxyHost(host, Integer.parseInt(port));
        httpclient.getHostConfiguration().setProxyHost( pxy);
        PostMethod currentMethod = new PostMethod( "http://mydomainb.com/myservice");
        currentMethod.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        currentMethod.setRequestBody( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><xmlcontent>content</xmlcontent>");
        // The following line doesn't have any impact.
        //currentMethod.setDoAuthentication(false);
        final int iResult = httpclient.executeMethod( currentMethod);
        String sResult = currentMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        System.out.println(sResult);
      }
      finally {
        httpclient = null;
      }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why HttpClient would be resulting in an authentication challenge, but using a standard UrlConnection gets through the proxy server fine?  Is there something fundamental that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251826/java-communication-fails-through-web-proxy-using-apache-httpclient

Comment: That doesn't help much, as it doesn't explain why HttpClient is causing authentication to occur - it has a couple of suggestions for adding NTLM authentication which is not want I want to do.